# String index out of range error when creating a palindrome program

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, indexing

I'm a beginner programmer and I tried to create a program to check if the word entered is a palindrome or not but I keep on getting this string index out of range error I am not sure why.

```
word= input("enter word")
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        if word[i] == word[len(word) - i]:
            count+=1
if count == len(word):
    print("yes it is")
else:
     print("no it is not")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word[len(word) - i]
```

supposing `word` is `"hello"`, you'll have `word[5 - i`], and since `i` is 0 you'll have `word[5]` which is out of bounds (valid indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4). So you'll need

```
if word[i] == word[len(word) - 1 - i]:
```